# How to install Ubuntu from windows

Tags: boot, server, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu server on a free partition, my hdd is divided into two partitions, the first holds windows, my programs and so on, the second one is completely empty. I can't make a bootable usb drive or put the iso on a dvd to boot from that. Can I install Ubuntu onto the partition, from my running windows partition (you could say, right now, as I'm writing this ;)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Install ubuntu using a live cd. There used to be a way to do that, but it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by first partitioning your HDD as usual. The official instructions are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

you'll need to select the disk from your bios, instructions can be found by searching your PC model "bios" in Google. once you boot from your disk. follow the official instructions. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server)

as far as I know there is no way to install server from within windows, I may be wrong though. Good Luck :)